# How do you upgrade a Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition from Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04?

Tags: upgrade, 15.04, dell, xps

I just got a Dell XPS 13 (2015) that came with Ubuntu 14.04 installed, I'd like to upgrade to 15.04, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, be sure you've done all the 14.04 updates (I had issues just doing this, but after a bunch of reboots and upgrade attempts, you'll eventually get it done).

Second, go into Update Manager and tell Ubuntu to show you all available version updates, the default with the pre-installed 14.04 is to show you nothing, not even LTSes.

Then you have to remove some things that cause issues with the upgrade, install a newer kernel, and update grub: ([src](http://from:%20https://plus.google.com/+MartinBachmann/posts/j6ACnNu9bur))

```
sudo dpkg -P oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms
sudo dpkg -P casper-memdisk
sudo apt-get install -f linux-image-3.19.0-20-generic
sudo update-grub
```

Do NOT REBOOT YET!

Now upgrade to 14.10 with:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

This should bring you up to 14.10. After the reboot into 14.10, check it with `lsb_release -a`, it should say 14.10.

Now run `sudo do-release-upgrade` again to upgrade to 15.04 or run "Software Updater" and it should say 15.04 is available and ask you to upgrade (assuming you've set it to notify you of non LTS versions).

Boom, that should be it. I had no issues going this route.

If you lose wireless, apparently you can do a usb tether. Plug your phone into the usb port and turn on usb tethering, then `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. Did not test this.

Comment: Many thanks for your effort, I was in the same position as you. However, following your exact steps resulted in an unstable system due to too many errors while upgrading, and kernel panic (blinking caps) when restarted. If anyone else also fail to upgrade, try following http://hgdev.co/installing-ubuntu-15-04-on-the-xps-13-9343-2015-a-complete-guide/ which worked perfectly. Way more steps, though.