# Ubuntu 15.04 doesn't boot on Dell XPS 13 2015

Tags: boot, upgrade, uefi, 15.04, xps

I wanted to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to the new Ubuntu 15.04 on my Dell XPS 14 2015 Developer Edition, because most issues seemed to be fixed in the live version.

Therefore I wiped the hole disk ([without doing it easier](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637360/how-do-you-upgrade-a-dell-xps-13-developer-edition-from-ubuntu-14-04-to-15-04)) and now the XPS isn't able to find any bootable media. Then I tried to install it with the help of [this guide](http://www.tecmint.com/ubuntu-15-04-installation-on-uefi-firmware/) which gave me the hint to create a new partition table.

The installation worked fine and I saw in the live version of Ubuntu that the system and my account under `/home` was installed.

But the notebook still can't find any bootable media. Are there any other aspects  that I didn't consider?

---

#### Update:

The problem could be solved by enabling UEFI booting in the BIOS (press F12 during the boot) and by disabling 'Legacy option ROMS'. Take a look at [this DELL blog post](http://www.dell.com/support/article/en/en/endhs1/SLN297060/EN). Follow the instructions and reinstall your system.

Comment: It seems to be issue with the version of ubuntu in dell xps which causing many issues like often hanging  and freezing.

Comment: @vembutech do you mean Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that GRUB is not installed or corrupted. Try installing grub again if you can login through coomand line (CTRL + ALT + F1).

Comment: I found this article to install GRUB on my machine. I tried the command `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` but I get an error: `Ìnstalling for i386-pc platform    grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of '/cow'`

Comment: @user3147268 check the following  [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254491/failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-cow)

Comment: I tried the commands under **If Your Grub Partition Contains A Full OS Install**:  `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt` returns that `/dev/sda1` is already mounted at `/mnt`. Next I entered `sudo chroot /mnt` and I got an error: `chroot: failed to run command '/bin/bash': no such file or directoy`. How is possible? Currently I'm using the default bash console.

Comment: The reference to `i386-pc` strongly suggests that the system was installed in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, or at least that your recovery medium was booted that way. Chances are you should be using an EFI/UEFI-mode install instead, since that's the native mode for essentially all modern firmware. Enabling BIOS/CSM/legacy support complicates the boot path and creates opportunities for problems such as the one you describe, as covered in more detail on [my Web page on the subject.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html)

Comment: @user3147268 Give it a shot to these commands. When I was in a similar situation and nothing worked ,only this solution fixed grub installation. 
`sudo mkdir /mnt/boot`
`sudo mount -t auto /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot`
`sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/boot --recheck /dev/sda`

Comment: I'll try them in a minute. As @RodSmith suggested I've changed the booting mode from BIOS to UEFI. Now I'm trying to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. By changing the boot mode to UEFI I was able to boot successfully after the installation. Now I only need to add some drivers for the internal WiFi card and I should ready to go.

Comment: I need to revoke my last update. However earlier I was able to boot successfully and enter my password to login. After trying to install the WiFi drivers I've still the same issues.

Comment: I found [this article](http://blog.mgor.se/2015/05/13/installing-ubuntu-15-04-on-dell-xps-13/) that describes the same issues after the installation. By trying to follow the steps (after the WiFi drivers) I entered `mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /mnt` but the shell showed an error:

`mount: special device /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root does not exist`

Comment: The `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` device might or might not exist on your system, depending on how you installed. Specifically, that's a device filename for an LVM setup; if you didn't use LVM, your root partition will be on a regular partition, like `/dev/sda2` or `/dev/sda6` or something like that. More broadly, posting the `RESULTS.txt` file from [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) may be helpful at this point.

Comment: @RodSmith was finally right. Now my XPS 13 boots fine. For more information take a look at the update section in my question above.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

1) Launch ubuntu on the live USB

2) follow the procedure to install Boot-Repair

3) Restart and your system will boot

4) From terminal update, upgrade and dist-upgrade and reboot

5) repeat 4) id you find some issue